# Functional test fails with csrf_protection = true

Tags: php, symfony, testing

In a functional test of user registration: when `csrf_protection: true`, registration fails even though registration succeeds in dev. Test succeeds when `csrf_protection: false`. (Application uses PUGXMultiUserBundle). I've tried clearing test cache, etc. Dumping `$this->client->getResponse()->getContent()` to file shows the registration form with all fields but password completed.  Stepping through a debug of the test shows the `_token` field submitted but seemingly stripped out of `fos_user_registration_form[]` before getting to the line `public function request($method, $uri, array $parameters = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null, $changeHistory = true)` in `Client.php`.

For now I've set `csrf_protection: false` in `config_test.yml` - not the best solution!

#### RegistrationFunctionalTest

```
namespace Truckee\UserBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
class RegistrationFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $volunteerValues;
    private $client;

    public function setup()
    {
        $classes = array(
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadFocusSkillData',
            'Truckee\MatchingBundle\DataFixtures\SampleData\LoadTemplateData',
        );
        $this->loadFixtures($classes);
        $this->client = static::createClient();

        $this->volunteerValues = array(
            'fos_user_registration_form' => array(
                'email' => 'hvolunteer@bogus.info',
                'username' => 'hvolunteer',
                'firstName' => 'Harry',
                'lastName' => 'Volunteer',
                'plainPassword' => array(
                    'first' => '123Abcd',
                    'second' => '123Abcd',
                ),
                'focuses' => array('1'),
                'skills' => array('14'),
            )
        );
    }


    public function submitVolunteerForm()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/register/volunteer');
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
        $this->client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $this->volunteerValues);
    }

    public function testRegisterVolunteer()
    {
        $this->submitVolunteerForm();

        $this->client->enableProfiler();
        if ($profile = $this->client->getProfile()) {
            $mailCollector = $this->client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
             $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());
        }
        $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("An email has been sent")')->count() > 0);
    }
...
}
```

#### registration form (snippet) showing `_token`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        {%if form._token is defined %}{{ form_widget(form._token) }}{% endif %}
        {{ form_row(form.firstName) }}
        {{ form_row(form.lastName) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation I discovered my own solution:
Add `'intention'  => 'registration',` to user form class!  Doh!

#### EDIT: above was NOT the solution!!!

The fundamental problem was using the array method (`$this->client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $this->volunteerValues);` of submitting the form.  Doing so excluded the csrf token!  Instead, I did this to allow the form's token field to be used:

```
public function submitVolunteerForm()
{
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/register/volunteer');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[email]'] = 'hvolunteer@bogus.info';
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[username]'] = 'hvolunteer';
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[firstName]'] = 'Harry';
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[lastName]'] = 'Volunteer';
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]'] = '123Abcd';
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]'] = '123Abcd';
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[focuses]'] = [1];
    $form['fos_user_registration_form[skills]'] = [14];

    $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
}
```